# How to send the email in PHP using Amazon SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I installed the SES server into my amazon ec2 server and I verified the emails and SMTP. I want to send the email through my contact form so I got the PHP code form amazon I installed the PHPMailer inside the **var/www/html** folder and I call the PHPMailer class different PHP file. I called the different files inside the **validate folder**. I can't understand where I'm missing the code details Images I attached down Please check and let me know where I made the mistake and Help me to fix these issues.

```
<?php
      //Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
    //This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';
    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
    // SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
    // SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
    //Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
    $mail->Port = 25;
    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    //Username to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'AKIA4I2MVSMJS34XXXX';
    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Jerad');
    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('test123@hotmail.com', 'Arul');
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress('welcome@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);
    $mail->Body= 'testing Success';
    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    //Attach an image file
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message sent!';
    }
    ?>
```

**After click send button I'm getting this message**

[image]

Comment: So, what exactly is the issue? What is the error message that you get? I have a feeling the Mail::factory line is something I have never heard of before.

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. that's why I confessed

Comment: $mail = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtpParams); 
after here i'm not getting error msg

Comment: did you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) with [PHP PEAR Mailing Class](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php). You are currently trying to use both.

Try using the [PHPMailer SMTP tutorial](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps) to send the mail instead of the PEAR class.

Comment: I tried this code I'm getting this error message 
Mailer Error: Message body empty.

I'm i'm not receive any mail

Comment: Instead of the $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__) line try using: $mail->Body= BODY;

Comment: I insert the body tag as you gave it gives some message authentication success 250 but I didn't receive mail

Comment: I used the host name like this
 $mail->Host = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post the whole new code?

Comment: I Uploaded my new what you gave and same time I uploaded what I'm getting the message after the click send button Please help me to fix this

Comment: At the RCPT line, the server asks for the email address to send mail to. Next line, your SMTP Mailer provides it. The three dots at the end of the message lines suggests there is more content that is maybe not able to fit into the box to display. Can you go into Developer Console in your browser, and view the network request when you press the 'Send' button and edit your answer to include the full response returned?

Answer (score 0):

I did like this now email is coming but it's going to spam

```
<?php
    //Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
                    require '../vendor/autoload.php';
            //Create a new PHPMailer instance
                    $mail = new PHPMailer;
            //Set who the message is to be sent from
                    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
            //Set an alternative reply-to address

            //Set who the message is to be sent to
                    $mail->addAddress($toAdd, 'TixRez');

            //Set the subject line
                    $mail->Subject = 'TixRez Client Registertion';
            //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
            //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
            //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__);
                    $mail->Body = 'Full Name - '.$name. '<br><br> Phone Number - '.$phone. '<br><br> Email - '.$email. '<br><br> Company - '.$company. '<br><br> Address - '.$address. '<br><br> City - '.$city. '<br><br> Zip Code - '.$zipCode. '<br><br> Country - '.$country_name. '<br><br> Web Address - '.$webAddress. '<br><br> Company Size - '.$comSize;
            //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
                    $mail->AltBody = $message;
            //Attach an image file
            //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
            //send the message, check for errors
                    if (!$mail->send()) {
                        echo 'Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    } else {
                        echo 'Message sent!';
                    }

    ?>
```

Comment: The $email need to be the domain associated with your Amazon SES account. As in the code in your original questions, I see you've used 'test@gmail.com'. Use $email as contact@tixrez.com or something similar.